# defining multimethod IllegalArgumentException No matching method: addMethod

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a namespace for doing dns lookups with Clojure, and I'm running into a strange problem. The following code compiles and works as expected.

```
(ns dmarced.dns)

(defmulti lookup-record
  (fn [type name]
    type))

(defmethod lookup-record :txt [_ name]
  [["foo"]])
```

On the other hand, if I want to name the method `lookup` like so:

```
(ns dmarced.dns)

(defmulti lookup
  (fn [type name]
    type))

(defmethod lookup :txt [_ name]
  [["foo"]])
```

It won't compile. The error I get is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: addMethod, compiling:(dmarced/dns.clj:7:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6875)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6625)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6001)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5380)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3972)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6866)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6669)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6924)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:372)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:363)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:453)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:419)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5677.invoke(core.clj:5893)
    at clojure.core$load.invokeStatic(core.clj:5892)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5876)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at user$eval5$fn__16.invoke(form-init1251542249642636935.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invokeStatic(form-init1251542249642636935.clj:1)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init1251542249642636935.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6927)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6917)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7379)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: addMethod
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$StaticMethodExpr.<init>(Compiler.java:1642)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$HostExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:1011)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6868)
    ... 37 more
Failed.
```

It feels like this should be something simple, but I'm not seeing it. I've checked and `lookup` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere else.

Using Clojure 1.8.0

EDIT: noisesmith pointed out it works fine in a vanilla Clojure project. A bit of experimenting shows me that if I remove the dependency on `[dnsjava/dnsjava "2.1.7"]` the problem goes away, but I still don't understand why it's occurring in the first place.

Comment: using clojure 1.8.0 I cannot replicate this error - there must be some other context - I can load the file as presented here without errors

Comment: Hmm.. your right, if I paste the code into a repl started outside my project in works fine, but inside my project it's produces the above error. I'm kind of stumped on where to look to try to shrink it down to a small example. The full project is here: https://source.waltonhoops.com/dmarced. Changing the name of the multi-method in the dns namespace to `lookup` and running `lein check` produces the error.